# Does Drupal have some kind of Structure system?

Tags: organic-groups

I looked all over but no result ...

I wonder if there is a Structure System for Drupal like: **Spaces - Sections - Groups - Blocks - etc**.

Where to use Spaces and may I have groups in spaces? The documentation is somehow messy, I'm lost. But there seems to be no good guides (like books) for a Drupal beginner.

**Edit**:

It takes time to find out what I need, where to install, etc.

Drupal 7 with Open Atrium 2 should be used for a Information an collaboration suite for a company. Login and all user-information and its roles comes over LDAP and active directory. So far I haven't got any problems.

But now I would like to build a user page:

- I take a layout with two cols.
- In the right column I have all the information read from active directory and user information.
- In the left column there should be some different things.

But I would be very happy if I could understand how to build a user page with all the logged in user information automatically where user will be redirected after logged in.

I don't know how the hierarchy in Drupal works:

- Do I need a space for all user who are logged in in Drupal?
- And do I have groups inside a space or can I have groups without a space?

**Edit**:

So please don't mind if I give you this advice:

Not to explain all this modules and for what they are all for but to give specific projects and go through this from the first plane and road-map over the modules which we need till the building and setup.

So we can see it quit from the other side. Starting from a project going through drupal. And not from Drupal and for what it could be all for.

In my case I should build a company platform for all employees with there personal date from active directory (LDAP) and build up a personal page for each employee with his personal data with Drupal.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Simple concepts in Drupal are `Nodes` and `Users`. Orchestrating large websites with dynamic sections and complex business takes time to learn how to integrate various drupal modules to meet your needs. Please rephrase your question with an exact scenario you want to achieve, eg "Users should be apart of a group and content posted only to 1 group" ...

Comment: Michael, I tried to "enhance" your question by integrating your own "answer" you added to it also. Please review my attempt to enhance your question (and correct where appropriate). Pretty sure that your "answer" (which in not what is considered an "answer" on Drupal.SE ...) will soon be removed by moderators. Just trying to get you going on Drupal.SE, OK?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) From your recent edit it's clear you're looking for a full tutorial on how to build your site - which we don't do here. As a Q+A site were building a repository of narrowly scoped knowledge, questions need to be clear and focused on a single, objectively answerable goal. Try breaking your task down into its smallest parts, and attack each individually. Then when you have a specific question about a specific part of your development, this is the place to ask. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to Drupal, you might have a hard time getting your head around the (amazing) [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module, and things like "context", etc. But it sounds that's part of what you're looking for. Watch the videos about [Learn Page manager](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-page-manager) for more details. After you reviewed these videos, you should understand various features that come with the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module ... but also its challenges.

As an alternative, you may want to give it a try to see how far you can get with any (or all?) of these modules:

- [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) (a typical alternative for using [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels)).
- [DataTables](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables) used in combination with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) (especially because of its client side search facilities).
- You might want to check also to what extend the features provided by [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module might help in your case.

Fairly sure that at some point you should also look at the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module.

## Video tutorials

- For anybody not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great (+ free) video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-the-rules-framework), organized in 7 chapters.
- Possibly also the similar [set of 8 video tutorials](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-flag-with-nodeone) about the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, often considered as a natural complement to the Rules module.
- The amazing set of videos to [Learn Organic Groups](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-organic-groups) might help to better understand what [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) is all about.
- While you're there, why not also review the [set of 30 video tutorials](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone) about the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your kindly advise. 
Rules, OGs, Flags, I even don't know whether I need this or not... ;-(